# How to retrieve a value of a selected item from a dropdown list using google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a dropdown list in a sheet, that can change the sheet name every time I select a value in it. So far this is what I was able to do:

```
 function renameSheet() {

  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//GET SHEET          
var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
var secondSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

//PART DROPDOWN
var partCell = secondSheet.getRange('A3'); 
var partLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var partRange = dataSheet.getRange('A2:A' + partLastRow);
var partRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(partRange).build();
partCell.setDataValidation(partRule);

  
var newName = secondSheet.getRange("A3");
secondSheet.setName(newName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top function changes the sheet name on sheets 0,9 and 10

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Sheet0','Sheet10','Sheet9'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1) {
    sh.setName(e.value);
  }    
}
```

This creates a drop down list of sheet names from a list in cell A1

```
function makeADropDown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Sheet9', 'Sheet10', 'Sheet0']);
  sh.getRange('A1').setDataValidation(r);
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I was wondering if you can recommend courses for me, I need to learn more and my sources are limited.

Comment: Actually,  I have learned the most by volunteering here.  It forces you to do your own research and if you don't and you say things that are wrong you will find out about it quickly from other volunteers.  But generally speaking  learning ECMAScript 2015 is very desirable and then digging into google apps script.  Also another good resource of learning is reading other peoples answers and working them out as tutorials.  I go through all of the top volunteers answers all of the time when I have nothing else to do just trying to learn what I can from them.  Learn how use browser developer tools.

Comment: Yess I think it'll do, even though the research is taking me a lot of time more than what I anticipated, and my best source for now is stack overflow. I have another question concerning automating "adding sheets", and resizing cells depending on images size. If you can help me with that too I'll be much thankful. Even with small hints. And thank you again.